# Is a QTreeView::sortByColumn() slot in QTreeView of Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt docs http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference, it's said that, If your model is sortable, i.e, if it reimplements the `QAbstractItemModel::sort()` function, both `QTableView` and `QTreeView`provide an API that allows you to sort your model data programmatically. In addition, you can enable interactive sorting (i.e. allowing the users to sort the data by clicking the view's headers), by connecting the `QHeaderView::sortIndicatorChanged() signal` to the `QTableView::sortByColumn() slot` or the `QTreeView::sortByColumn() slot`, respectively. However, the`QTreeView::sortByColumn()` is not a slot in `QTreeView` in Qt 5.4. Is there any thing wrong?The source code in *Src/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.h* shows that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QTreeView::sortByColumn` wasn't a slot before: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qtreeview.html#sortByColumn

And `QTreeView::sortByColumn` isn't a slot now: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#sortByColumn

There is nothing "wrong" with this implementation. The behavior of Qt 5 QTreeView will work exactly like a Qt 4 QTreeView with respect to `sortByColumn`.

Comment: Thanks very much. So maybe there's something wrong with the official document.